# Play framework stack trace logging and logging configuration

Tags: scala, logging, playframework

With play framework's default logger, I get full exceptions' stack traces in play's application log, and an abbreviated version of the same stack traces in the console. I have three basic questions about the logging:

1. In one case, I feel there may be some information missing. What does something like `... 3 common frames omitted` actually mean, and can I somehow configure to see those omitted frames?
2. How do I control whether the console shows a full stack trace v.s. a partial one v.s. just some exception title without a stack trace?
3. Can I replace the default logger with any of the following ones, or should I use those ones only for my own logging but keep the framework logging as is? will switching to those loggers break the non-blocking nature of play? [scala-logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging), [log4s](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging), [zero-log](https://code.google.com/p/zero-log/).

Hopefully, with your answer, I can focus more on my application and less so on logging infrastructure, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

1. Logback (just like the JRE) ommits common frames when it's printing a stack trace. See the [JRE description of how frames are elided](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()).
2. Play uses Logback. You can alter the configuration. Have a look at the [logback layout docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) and the [Play logging configuration docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger). Particularly look at the `xException` setting.
3. You can try TypeSafe's  scala-logging framework if you want. If it integrates with Logback or slf4j then it might nicely with Play. By default Play doesn't use Logback's async appender (although maybe it should?) so there's no issue about blocking or non-blocking to worry about.

Comment: I am not really following the JRE jargon explaining common frames eliding. Does this at the bottom line say that omitted "frames" are always duplicate anyway?

Comment: What about #3 and other mentioned logging frameworks? I will probably consult the google group and post back here.

Comment: 1. Yes, the frames are duplicates, because the exceptions are nested within each other. Imagine f calls g which calls h. Then h throws an exception, then g catches it and throws it wrapped in another exception. Both g and h have f as a common stack frame, so it may as well only be shown once.

Comment: 3. Sorry I don't know enough about other logging farmeworks to make a recommendation. Personally, I'd just use Play's logging or Logback or make my own small wrapper around Logback.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! and that's my plan around the logging indeed :)